# Grails 1.2.0 Deployment Problems: org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: hibernate, spring, grails

I'm having a frustrating problem with my Grails application. I'm able to run the application using both run-app and run-war without any issues, but when I try to deploy to a container, I get an exception that I'm not sure how to interpret. I've tried deploying on Glassfish, Tomcat, and Jetty, and I have the same issue in all three containers.

Any help in understanding what could cause this, and what underlying problems I should look for, would be extremely appreciated.

Stack log follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Type [null] is not a basic type or a domain class and cannot be mapped. Either specify a type within the [mapping] block or use a basic type (String, Integer etc.)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:714)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext.refresh(GrailsWebApplicationContext.java:153)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:68)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
2010-02-19 09:30:18.316:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Type [null] is not a basic type or a domain class and cannot be mapped. Either specify a type within the [mapping] block or use a basic type (String, Integer etc.):
org.hibernate.MappingException: Type [null] is not a basic type or a domain class and cannot be mapped. Either specify a type within the [mapping] block or use a basic type (String, Integer etc.)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindCollectionWithJoinTable(GrailsDomainBinder.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(GrailsDomainBinder.java:502)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.access$100(GrailsDomainBinder.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder$GrailsCollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(GrailsDomainBinder.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1163)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:329)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.java:143)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1148)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:81)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:714)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext.refresh(GrailsWebApplicationContext.java:153)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:68)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. A static mapping block caused the error.

```
static mapping { contents type 'text' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error.  I cleaned my app (grails clean) before generating the war and the problem went away.  Maybe there were references to old domain classes, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I rain into the same problem, for me it happened once I switched to Grails 1.2. The solution was not so obvious, the stacktrace certainly didn't shed any light on it.

You can't have domain objects w/ relationships such as hasMany declared in the same file. Each domain object should be declared in a separate file.

See http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=80964

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to raise in a set of very different conditions.

It happened to me upgrading an application from grails 1.1 to grails 1.2: in this case the trigger was an enum definition in the same file as the domain class using the enum: this didn't cause any problem under 1.1, while in 1.2 I got the infamous:

```
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Type [null] is not a basic type or a domain class and cannot be mapped. 
Either specify a type within the [mapping] block or use a basic type (String, Integer etc.)
```

**putting the enum in a separate file solved the problem.**

So it seems that grails 1.2 is a bit more picky about what goes in a domain class source file, respect to 1.1 ....